# Cocoa Espresso Style Preference Pane Tabs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tabs, preferences

Wondering how to implement tabs in the same style as Espresso.app:

[image: Espresso preferences window.]

Is there a native class/view to use or is this done with a 3rd party solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight NSToolbarItems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566793/highlight-nstoolbaritems)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you want to use a 3rd party solution like [BWToolkit](http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/), you can simply use a standard `NSToolbar`, that sends selection notifications to one of your controller classes. You can then use an `NSTabView` to switch between the panels, and in your `IBAction` method (that receives selection notifications) you can determine which item is selected, and programmatically switch your `NSTabView` to the proper index.

Answer (score 3):

That's a standard `NSToolbar` with a delegate allowing selectable items. However, you're probably wanting the panel resizing behaviour that Espresso implements.

Take a look at Dave Batton's [`DBPrefsWindowController`](https://github.com/kgn/DBPrefsWindowController) for a way to do this.