# NSToolbarItem not selectable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am building my NSToolbarItem(s) programmatically but they are not selectable. The ones added from the interface builder are selectable because there i have the option of checking the 'Selectable
' option. But the NSToolbarItem class has no setSelectable method.

The **NSToolbarDelegate** protocol is implemented and the **toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers** method is called but they are still disabled after returning the same identifiers the **toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers** method returns

Developing on OS X 10.10, targeting 10.7

Edit:

```
- (NSArray *) toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar *)toolbar{
NSMutableArray* ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSToolbarItem* item in [_my_toolbar items]){
    [ids addObject:item.itemIdentifier];
}

NSLog(@"Selectable ids are %@", ids);
return ids;
```

}

This is my implementation.(All the items should be selectable);

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566793/highlight-nstoolbaritems

Comment: Not quite. I updated my question with the toolbarSelectableItemIdentifiers implementation